# Extract number from string and replace?

Tags: python

So right now, my code is working as intended from what I know. But, I am incapable of putting together either a small module or another few lines to extract an integer number from users Input and inflate it by 1.

```
dictZero = [ "zero", "none", "null", "nil" ]
dictOne = [ "juan", "one", "won" ]
dictTwo = [ "two", "to", "too", "tu" ]
dictThree = [ "three" ]
dictFour = [ "four", "fore", "for" ]

userInput = input ( "Enter your sentence to inflate: " )


for i in userInput.split():              
    for e in dictFour:
        if e in i:
            userInput = userInput.replace ( e, "five" )                
    for d in dictThree:
        if d in i:
            userInput = userInput.replace ( d, "four" )                
    for c in dictTwo:
        if c in i:
            userInput = userInput.replace ( c, "three" )                
    for b in dictOne:
        if b in i:
            userInput = userInput.replace ( b, "two" )                
    for a in dictZero:
        if a in i:
            userInput = userInput.replace ( a, "one" )


print ( userInput )
```

Sample Input:

> Before we begin to do anything at 1630.

Sample Output:

> Befive we begin three do anything at 1631.

Without over-complicating and changing my code significantly, what can I do to simply +1 any number in the input string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ignore the `1630` at the end of the sentence, `str.replace` can just do replacements for words on the whole line, without needing to split it up by word.

If you want to add decimal numbers as well, you will need to go character by character, which will add some more complexity to the code.

```
dictZero = [ "zero", "none", "null", "nil" ]
dictOne = [ "juan", "one", "won" ]
dictTwo = [ "two", "to", "too", "tu" ]
dictThree = [ "three" ]
dictFour = [ "four", "fore", "for" ]

userInput = input ( "Enter your sentence to inflate: " )

for i in dictFour:
    userInput = userInput.replace(i, 'five')
for i in dictThree:
    userInput = userInput.replace(i, 'four')
for i in dictTwo:
    userInput = userInput.replace(i, 'three')
for i in dictOne:
    userInput = userInput.replace(i, 'two')
for i in dictZero:
    userInput = userInput.replace(i, 'one')

output = ''
num = ''
for c in userInput:  # Going char by char to find decimal values
    if c.isdigit():  # is this char a digit?
        num += c  # if so remember it
    else:
        if num: # if we just found a whole number
            output += str(int(num) + 1) # add 1 and append the string
        num = ''
        output += c  # Append any non-decimal character


print(output)
```

Input:

> Before we begin to do anything at 1630.

Output:

> Befive we begin three do anything at 1631.

Note that this will not add `float` or negative values in the string, only `int`s.

Comment: I can actually understand this code. But it doesn't actually work =/ I attempted throwing it in and it doesn't print anything even with print ( output ) or what I previously had print ( userInput ).

Comment: @Twissted Strange, I am able to run it fine.  Does it work if you run it on its own, without inserting it into your code?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. It doesn't work when it's by itself either for me i'm just going to go ahead with another method that's out of my ability but works. School is hard >.>. Really appreciate your time to help me out and simplifying the code for someone new

Answer (score 0):

Criteria unclear, this is how I would do it.

```
import re

word_dict = dict.fromkeys(["zero", "none", "null", "nil"], 'one')
word_dict.update(dict.fromkeys([ "juan", "one", "won" ], 'two'))
word_dict.update(dict.fromkeys([ "two", "to", "too", "tu" ], 'three'))
word_dict.update(dict.fromkeys([ "three" ], 'four'))
word_dict.update(dict.fromkeys([ "four", "fore", "for" ], 'five'))

userInput = input ( "Enter your sentence to inflate: " )

for i in word_dict.keys():
    userInput = re.sub(i, word_dict[i], userInput)
digits = re.compile(r'\d+')
userInput = digits.sub(lambda m: str(int(m.group(0)) + 1), userInput)

print ( userInput )
```

Sample run:

> Enter your sentence to inflate: 'Before we begin to do anything at 1630.'
>
> Befivee we begin three do anything at 1631.

Comment: If I understood how dicts worked and use something like that, then it works 100%. But what I have for code is what I am capable of. Therefore, I cannot use something as complicated as this to solve my problem. Thank you for input and your time